# C++ getline(string) special characters such as ä ö å

Tags: c++, special-characters, getline

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while.
I have code a bit like this:

```
std::string name;
getline(std::cin, name);
std::cout << name;
```

Now the problem is that when I enter letters "å" "ä" and "ö", 
they turn out as † „ and ”

Currently I am fixing this by running a for loop through the string, replacing them back to å ä ö and it seems to be working just fine, however I was wondering if there is a better way for fixing them?
I tried looking on Google and here on Stack Overflow for but couldn't find an answer to this problem.

EDIT:

I am using windows 7 and the problem appears to be with getline and setlocale(LC_ALL, "fin")
How ever, if I were to remove this it wouldn't display `cout << "öä"` correctly forcing me to do `cout << "\224\204"`, so I guess that i have to stick with for looping.

Comment: It might be useful to specify what operating system you are working on.

Comment: Looks like Scientologists are trying to convert you. Run away.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::wstring`?

Comment: Just tried wstring, no luck.

Comment: If You are running it on Windows, here is some research of this problem https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/